# When I run my app on debug mode I received "Invariant Violation: Calling synchronous methods on native modules is not supported in Chrome"

Tags: react-native

Image:

[image]

Text:

> Invariant Violation: Calling synchronous methods on native modules is not supported in Chrome.
> Consider providing alternative methods to expose this method in debug mode, e.g. by exposing constants ahead-of-time.
>
> Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
> This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.

Comment: You may need to add a sample of code to your question, so readers can see what might cause this.